# 100% Height Columns in CSS

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    &nbsp;
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="col1">
        Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>
    </div>
    <div id="col2">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div id="col3">
        Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum
    </div>
</div>
​<div id="footer">
    &nbsp;
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

CSS:

```css
#header{background:#aaa;height:100px}
#wrapper{background:#000;float:left}
#col1{background:#f00;float:left;width:300px}
#col2{background:#0f0;float:left;width:5px;height:100%} /* DOESN'T WORK */
#col3{background:#ff0;float:left;width:300px}
#footer{background:#aaa;height:100px;clear:both}​
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ya9RR/16/

How do I make any of the `col` to have 100% height?

Comment: Why can't you set the height to 300px?

Comment: Height is flexible; because content is generated by the CMS.

Comment: In that case, I don't know that it's possible with purely CSS. You could, however, write a simple script to pull the height of the tallest column and apply it to all three.

Comment: I can obviously do that with JS but there must be some sort of hack/trick which lets me do this in CSS.

Comment: Please review the related section to the bottom right of this page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the outer containers of the Columns to also take up 100% height, as % is relative to its parent.

html:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="col1">
        Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>
    </div>
    <div id="col2">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div id="col3">
        Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>​
```

css:

```
body, html {height: 100%;}
#wrapper{background:#000;float:left; height: 100%;}
#col1{background:#f00;float:left;width:300px;height:100%}
#col2{background:#0f0;float:left;width:5px;height:100%}
#col3{background:#ff0;float:left;width:300px;height:100%}
```

​
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ya9RR/14/

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways of doing this: http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/ I like this one: http://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/

```
#col1, #col2, #col3 {
    min-height: 300px;
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
    _height: 300px;
}
```

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ya9RR/8/

Comment: This sets the height to 300px not 100%.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I thought you just wanted the 3 columns to be the same size, based on the longest. Did you try the other answer? That fiddle he added seems to do what you want.